# Problems building web deploy package

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, webdeploy

Using visual studio I was able to configure a profile to create a web deploy package zip. I named the profile "deploy". I want to be able to do this from CI. This is the command line I have so far. I've been throwing every combination of options I've seen in the dozen blog posts out there:

```
msbuild HelloBeanstalk4.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=deploy /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU" /p:PackageLocation="D:\x.zip" /p:OutputPath="d:" /p:DeployTarget=deploy /tv:14.0
```

When I run this it just spits out the contents of the /bin as well as a _PublishedWebsites directory with the site files in it. It doesn't make a zip file. I am using VS2013 to build either a 4.0 or 4.5 site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio what is the file path for the setting `Publish | Connection | Package Location`? Mine is set to `obj\Release\Package\package.zip`

When you Publish in Visual Studio does it create the zip file in that location?

When I run the command in the folder with the .csproj it builds the package zip in the location I specified in the profile:

```
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=deploy
```

**UPDATE:**

Using VS 2013 Pro, below are the contents of my `./Properties/PublishProfiles/deploy.pubxml` file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>obj\Release\Package\package.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DeployIisAppPath />
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
       ...
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Compared to your `pubxml` file any notable differences?

Comment: Yes it publishes to the location I have specified when I use Visual Studio. It doesn't make a zip file anywhere in the source tree when I use the command line. In fact if I use your command it gives me an error requiring me to supply Configuration, Platform and OutputPath